# Fully Controlled server side filtering with pagination in react-table (v7) with Laravel 6+

Tags: reactjs, laravel-6, react-table-v7

I was working with React-Table v7 with API on Laravel 6+. I am done with pagination but now I would like to implement serverside filtering with multiple columns.

I want a simple example of filtering in react-table v7 with laravel as server

Comment: finally managed to get it done by following some docs and my own understanding of react hooks

Comment: Please share your solution.